# Trying to display a googleMap :$element is an unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm new with angularJs. I'm trying to display a googleMap.  when I got the exception $element unkown Provider. The code I m testing is a code I found while searching .Actually I'm not getting it very much .

html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>  </title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="../angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../angular/angular-route.js"></script>


<script src="../src/controllers/app.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
    <figure data-ng-controller="MapController">  
      <gmap></gmap>
    </figure> 
    </body>
```

My script is :

```
myAppControllers.controller('MapController',function($scope,$element){

    console.log("tessstttt ");
    $scope.showMap();
    $scope.showMap = function()
    {
     const mapEl = $element.find('gmap')[0];
      const mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {lat: 34.075328, lng: -118.330432}       
      };
      const gmap = new google.maps.Map(mapEl, mapOptions);
      $scope.gmap = gmap;
    };
});
```

Comment: do you actually wan t to use this code or, can I give a solution with good practices in google map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats its no the best way to make a simple google map. Here its a over easy example with funcionally fiddle to check this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerFirst">
<div id="maps"></div>
hello
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ControllerFirst',function($scope){
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 2),
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps"),mapOptions);
});
```

You can check this working in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/javierif/p16cyuha/

Comment: thanks a lot I tested it and it 's working well with me I added as well some markers from My database . What I m trying to do now is trying to find the nearest places to my location. Do you have some example or tutorial because I feel lost !